# Parte do grid esta oculto no chrome

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

problemas com o chrome. A princípio estou trabalhando somente em localhost e na versão 3 do bootstrap, como posso melhorar o CSS ?

No Firefox mostra o site completo, mas no chrome ele oculta (o grid que chamei de publicidade), é uma imagem e o plugin de uma página do facebook.

**Conforme imagens**:
Imagem no Firefox (correto): https://prnt.sc/jnb7t1

Imagem no **Chrome** (**incorreto**): https://prnt.sc/jnb811

**Como posso corrigir com o CSS** ? ou Existe outra forma ?
Obrigado!

```
<!-- BOX - PUBLICIDADE -->
<div class="publicidade tarja">
  <div class="container">

    <!-- BOX - DELIVERY + FACEBOOK -->
    <div class="row">

      <!-- BOX - DELIVERY -->
      <div class="col-md-8 delivery">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/800x340" class="img-responsive" />  
      </div><!-- col-md-8 -->

      <!-- BOX - FACEBOOK -->       
      <div class="col-md-4 facebook"> 

        <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Ffacebook&tabs=timeline&width=340&height=500&small_header=false&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true&appId=748328198670638" width="360" height="320" style="border:none;overflow:hidden;width:100%;" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>

      </div><!-- col-md-4 -->

    </div><!-- row -->

  </div><!-- container -->
</div><!-- publicidade -->
```

Comment: O incorreto é no Chrome? Vc colocou os dois como sendo do "Firefox".

Comment: Corrigi, foi um erro de ortografia mesmo... Mas o erro permanece!

Comment: Cara no meu Chrome ficou normal com o CSS default do Bootstrap. Deve ter sido algo a mais que vc colocou ai no seu código. Mas só como o que vc postou na pergunta aqui rodou normal...

Comment: Vou verificar se corrijo e aviso...
Obrigado Hugo!

Comment: Qual o CSS dessas classes `publicidade tarja`?

Comment: publicidade é o nome da div só...
Já a tarja ele tem um margin-top: 50px